# I need to fix memory leaks with TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

These are the memory leaks that I am getting: http://twitter.com/AWEHOFFICIAL/status/221182174811004929/photo/1/large

Comment: Edit: I am using ARC and storyboards

Comment: Probably time to start debugging then isn't it :)

Comment: Yes indeed I will try my best.

Comment: Im not really sure I see the point of you posting on here though?

Comment: Im not an experienced programmer thus the chances of me solving this are very slim. I will try my best to solve it but if not then I will need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the righthand pane you should see a stacktrace of the leak, which will help you track it down.  You might also attempt to profile with the debug version of your app, in order to get better symbol info.  This can be achieved by modifying the project's scheme within Xcode.

Comment: Apparently according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880336/obj-c-memory-leak-of-malloc-48-bytes-in-strdup-frame this leak has nothing to do with my code. Since it's Malloc 48. Users have said that this is a bug with the framework.

Comment: @James check the stacktrace anyway; I don't think you can rely on the size of the malloc to tell if it's framework or your code.

Comment: Yes indeed if you would kindly follow this link https://twitter.com/AWEHOFFICIAL/status/221191740730781696/photo/1/large can you tell me if it is my code or framework please?

Comment: @James It looks like you called `[NSNotificationCenter addObserver]`; did you call `[NSNotificationCenter removeObserver]`?

Comment: I dont remember calling [NSNotificationCenter addObserver];

Comment: @James OK, so it must be part of the NIB loading process, so you're in the clear by the look of it.

Comment: Thats good to hear thank you for your help. As I said before It must be a bug with the framework